# firebase notification using firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

**i want a notification to be showed when any user post any new message in my android app**,
the notification should be showed to all the users who are using the app,
with the message in the notification like whatsapp notification .
**i am using firebaserealtime database for saving and retrieving message.**
please let me know how i can achieve it.
'

i have a question  also? that if i make a service for onChildAdded() in my android ,
which listens for data change of messages than what will be the impact of it on battery,
since a service would be running in the background.

thankyou for your suggestions and help

Comment: "How to add notifications to my chat app" is too broad to provide a short answer. But most apps use a tool like [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to accomplish this, indeed in part to prevent having to keep a connection open just for the app (which puts extra drain on the battery).

Comment: Refer this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-3

Comment: Frank van Puffelen i want to use  firebase cloud messanging but the problem is that currently i am using firebase database, for database purpose not mysql ,but all the docs and google are for using fcm with mysql database not with firebaserealtime databse, 
if the above is not possible,
Please tell me  a way out for using mysql database just for notification purposes ,the database will be firebaserealtime database but for notification it will send a request to a mysql server  and then to android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). It is another service that they provide, here is a snippet from the website:

> Using FCM, you can notify a client app that new email or other data is available to sync. You can send notification messages to drive user reengagement and retention.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.